# Is Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelenskyy the moshiach?

Tags: messiah

Okay so hear me out. This is going to sound crazy but is President Volodymyr Zelenskyy the Moshiach? I mean hypothetically if he lives through this war. I read the sages the moshiach would be a ruling monarch, but the monarchs nowadays are only for show, so technically he would be a politician. He would unite the nations and fight evil, isn't that kinda what he's doing now? His grandparents died in the holocaust and I looked up Zelenskyy which has royal lineage. He is also said to be well versed in Torah. I can't exactly know how well he knows Torah I mean, I do know he's a great military leader.

Comment: Maybe moshiach Ben yosef

Comment: he's a puppet leader in charge of a Neo nazi government that votes against jewish interest in Israel and from any way the public can observe of him he isn't even observant. How is this even a thought? wild

Comment: @Dude Your comment confuses me because I see this photo: https://w2.chabad.org/media/images/1089/SnxU10893016.JPG?_i=_n504BC99DD0473598AAE3BCDC5D75568D of him with Rabbis.

Comment: @Dude His grandfather, Semyon (Simon) Ivanovych Zelenskyy, served as an infantryman, reaching the rank of Colonel,[5] in the Red Army (in the 57th Guards Motor Rifle Division)[22] during World War II; Semyon's father and three brothers died in the Holocaust.

Comment: I absolute do not wish to get into politics especially on here because this is for Torah. I do not appreciate your comment. The answer of what qualifies for the Moshiach is more appropriate.

Comment: This is the time we must do the most good for the world.

Answer (score 3):

וְאִם יַעֲמֹד מֶלֶךְ מִבֵּית דָּוִד הוֹגֶה בַּתּוֹרָה וְעוֹסֵק בְּמִצְוֹת כְּדָוִד אָבִיו. כְּפִי תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב וְשֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה. וְיָכֹף כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לֵילֵךְ בָּהּ וּלְחַזֵּק בִּדְקָהּ. וְיִלָּחֵם מִלְחֲמוֹת ה'. הֲרֵי זֶה בְּחֶזְקַת שֶׁהוּא מָשִׁיחַ. (אִם עָשָׂה וְהִצְלִיחַ וּבָנָה מִקְדָּשׁ בִּמְקוֹמוֹ וְקִבֵּץ נִדְחֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל הֲרֵי זֶה מָשִׁיחַ בְּוַדַּאי. וִיתַקֵּן אֶת הָעוֹלָם כֻּלּוֹ לַעֲבֹד אֶת ה' בְּיַחַד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר כִּי אָז אֶהְפֹּךְ אֶל עַמִּים שָׂפָה בְרוּרָה לִקְרֹא כֻלָּם בְּשֵׁם ה' וּלְעָבְדוֹ שְׁכֶם אֶחָד):
Now, if a king should arise from the House of David who is versed in Torah and engages in Commandments, as did David his forefather, in accordance with both the Written and the Oral Torahs, and he enjoins all of Israel to follow in its ways and encourages them to repair its breaches, and he fights the Wars of G-d, then he may be presumed to be the Messiah. If he succeeds in his efforts and defeats the enemies around and builds the Sanctuary in its proper place and gathers the dispersed of Israel, he is definitely the Messiah.

https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.11.4

The Rambam says one of the requirments of mashiach is he observes the Torah and forces the jews to observe it.

Comment: "forces" coud also mean  encourage